# Is it possible to connect two selectOutputIn blocks with a selectOutputOut block in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I know it is possible with the normal select output blocks, but my complete model is big making it very messy to draw all the lines. See picture as clarification

[image]

Answer (score 1):

not with these blocks, they are designed to *not* draw lines. While the `SelectOutput` blocks are designed to draw lines. So switch to what you need (or refine your actual problem as the answer to your question is simply: no)

Or as the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/selectoutputin.html#selectoutputin) puts it:
[image]